# actual usage of 'grub-mkimage --config= '

Tags: grub

On Linux, with GRUB 2 Bootloader, I try to figure out the actual usage of the `--config=` option in `grub-mkimage`. The `man 1 grub-mkimage` on this topic:

> `-c, --config=FILE`
>   embed FILE as an *early* config

My first guess would be `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` -> but then there's a separate command to build this file, which leads me away from this guess. Another guess is `/boot/config-3.16.0-4-686-pae` (`file`'s output: "Linux make config build file, ASCII text"). The other files I found were not ASCII but binary files, which also isn't much likely to be meant, I guess.

**Question**: What file, or kind of file, could be meant?

---

**UPDATE**: Found this one in the [gnu.org documentation for GRUB 2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#configfile), among commands for the GRUB prompt:

> `configfile file`
>        Load FILE as a configuration file.  If FILE defines any menu
>        entries, then show a menu containing them immediately.

Probably the same file? Funny sidenot: The online manual seemingly doesn't mention this option.

---

**UPDATE 2**: Found the following line in  the output of `grub-mkrescue --output grub.iso --verbose`

> grub-mkrescue: info: grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc' --prefix '/boot/grub' --output '/tmp/grub.ZiXwO6/boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' --format 'i386-pc-eltorito' --compression 'auto' **--config '/tmp/grub.UtCj8W'** 'biosdisk' 'iso9660'`

So **`--config '/tmp/grub.UtCj8W'`** rules out `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` .. somehow? And no, I didn't find anything mentioned about configuration when executing `grub-install` with verbose output activated

---

**UPDATE 3**: `man 1 grub2-mkstandalone` opens `man 3 grub2-mkstandalone`, but issuing `man 3 grub2-mkstandalone` leads to an error message. Also: `grub-mkimage --config=` seems to appear in the man page only but neither in `--help` nor in `--usage` output.

Answer (score 7):

`grub-mkimage` is the key central for `grub` to build all other stuffs when needed.
For example, `grub-[install,mkstandalone,mkrescue]` all refer to the use of `grub-mkimage`, so once `grub-mkimage` is understood, everything looks easy to do.

`grub-mkimage` has 2 ways to "attach" a config file to its image :

1. option `-c`,`--config=File`  (embed FILE as an early config)
2. option `-m`,`--memdisk=file` (embed FILE as a *memdisk* containing eventually config file)

Example: embedded config `[$prefix]/boot/grub/[x86_64-efi/]grub.cfg`

The *memdisk* is a virtual disk device viewed by `grub`, having a `tarfs` filesystem; the various modules sitting there are "ready for use", meaning they
can be loaded by `insmod` directly. But they are not directly callabled as the
"preloaded modules" as those in the options `--modules="blah blah...:"`
(the last ones are similar to drivers loaded in `initramfs` in Linux OS)

The best demonstration for this assertion is using one line command
to remaster a `livecd_only_biosPC_awared` into a    `livecd_isohybrid_bios_and_efi_awared`

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev TinyCorePure64-6.0.iso -outdev new.iso \
-cpr efime.img /boot -- \
-rm /boot/isolinux/boot.cat -- \
-mkdir /.disk /boot/grub -- \
-cpr grub.cfg /boot/grub -- \
-cpr info /.disk/info -- \
 -as mkisofs  -graft-points -volid "tinyefi" -r -J -l -eltorito-boot boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -eltorito-catalog boot/isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/efime.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat
```

where

1. ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/tinycorelinux/6.x/x86_64/archive/6.0/TinyCorePure64-6.0.iso
2. `grub.cfg` is plain config to reproduce `isolinux.cfg` of original live ISO
3. The bootloader `efime.img` is obtained with

   `grub-mkimage -m memdisk -O x86_64-efi -o grubx64.efi --compression=xz  disk part_msdos part_gpt linux linux16 loopback normal configfile test search search_fs_uuid search_fs_file true iso9660 test  search_label efi_uga efi_gop gfxterm gfxmenu gfxterm_menu fat ext2 ntfs cat echo ls memdisk tar`
4. The simplest *memdisk* contains `(memdisk)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as 
   early-embedded config file.

All about this will soon appear as exercises on grub-mkBootx64.efi @sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox

Comment: I have a question: Is it possible to specify the grub.cfg by location (like `configfile ...` in GRUB) instead of embedding the grub.cfg? The difference is if you burn an ISO and afterwards upgrade your kernel. Then the grub.cfg embedded will refer to the old kernel names.

Answer (score 4):

[From the Grub Manual 2.04, Section 6.5](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Embedded-configuration):

> GRUB supports embedding a configuration file directly into the core image, so that it is loaded before entering normal mode. This is useful, for example, when it is not straightforward to find the real configuration file, or when you need to debug problems with loading that file.
> ...
> To embed a configuration file, use the `-c` option to `grub-mkimage`.
> ...
> The embedded configuration file may not contain menu entries directly, but may only read them from elsewhere using [the] `config file` [command].

Based on this, the `--config` option is intended to embed a config file that contains commands that are used to help initialize grub, before it begins it's normal operations. It is NOT intended to embed a full `grub.cfg` with menu entries etc.